# Document_Open does not work in Word 2007 template

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

For employees to work, I need to put some functionality into the Document_Open macro. I want to put this macro in a template (.dot) and place it on the network. Office 2007 is installed on most machines, and I'm testing on it.

I create a document, insert the macro code, save it as a template (.dot). I use the following macro code as a test:

```
Sub Document_Open()
MsgBox "ABC" 
End Sub
```

Next, I create a document (.doc) and change the document template on my created template. I allow the execution of macros, the macro work. I save and close the document, when I reopen the document and enable macros, our macro does not work. What the problem is I can’t understand. Thank!

Comment: Your problem description is unclear... **Where** (in what module) is the macro? `Document_Open` *must* be in the `ThisDocument` module. Otherwise, use `Sub AutoOpen`. I do not know what you mean by "...change the document template on my created template." But what happens if you double-click the template with the macro to create a new document based on that template, save it, then re-open?

Comment: Document_Open  in the ThisDocument. In case if i double-click the template with the macro to create a new document based on that template, save it, then re-open then macro does not work.

Comment: Go into `ThisDocument`. Select all the lines of the macro and click the "Comment" button (puts a `'` in front of them). Go to the drop-down at the top-left of the code window and select `Document`. Go to the drop-down next to it, at the right, and select `Open`. This will write the code stub for you, with the correct syntax. Put in your test `MsgBox` and test again.

Comment: Note: don't forget to use the `@` symbol to ensure people get notifications when you answer in comments. For example: @cindymeister

Comment: @cindymeister What's this Document tab? In the macro editing window? In the main window the Word? Did you manage to repeat my situation? Did the macro work?

Comment: You said in a comment that you have `Document_Open` in the `ThisDocument` code module. So select/display that code module - thus, you're in the "macro editing window". Comment out that macro. Use the ***dropdown boxes*** at the top of the window to first select `Document` from the list on the left; then `Open` from the list on the right.

Comment: @CindyMeister This solution worked for me with a similar issue. The syntax it generated was exactly the same as what I had, but it started working again, so Im happy with it